# How is it that I can initialize a slice of pointers like this?

Tags: go

I was surprised I could initialize a slice of pointers in this way:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type index struct {
    i, j int
}

func main() {
    indices := []*index{{0, 1}, {1, 3}} // Why does this work?

    fmt.Println(*indices[1])
}
```

I was expecting to have to write something more verbose like:

```
indices := []*index{&index{0, 1}, &index{1, 3}}
```

Where would I find this in the documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals):

> Within a composite literal of array, slice, or map type T, elements or
>   map keys that are themselves composite literals may elide the
>   respective literal type if it is identical to the element or key type
>   of T. Similarly, elements or keys that are addresses of composite
>   literals may elide the &T when the element or key type is *T.

Basically, it already knows each element will be a `*index`, so it saves you having to actually type `&index` over and over again.

If the slice type is not the same as the element type (perhaps it is a slice of an interface type), you would have to specify the type of each element like so:

`indices := []interface{}{&index{0, 1}, &index{1, 3}}`

Comment: Thanks. It is interesting that you can elide the type in the context of an array, slice or map but not in a struct or variable.

Comment: Yeah, it would almost make sense for `var i *index = {1,3}` to be valid, but it isn't. It's just as easy to use `i := &index{1,3}` though.